# Set height of go to button in beamer class

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, frame, button

I can set width of go to button in beamer presentation with the following code. How can I set height of go to button?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample}
\begin{itemize}
\item \href{./myfile.pdf}{\beamergotobutton{\makebox[3cm]{Click here}}}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to set height of go to button to say 2cm.

Comment: Judging by the source, the button's vertical dimension is fixed and so is its drawing. You could define a different template or your own command that's just using TikZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beamer hard codes the height of beamer buttons to 8pt. Unless you want to redefine the [complete button](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty#L266-L312), that's not easy to change.

However the beamer button is basically just a picture. You can replace it with any other drawing. For example you can recreate it in tikz:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mygotobutton}[2][]{%
  \begingroup%
  \usebeamercolor{button border}%
  \usebeamercolor{button}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \node[fill=button.bg!66, draw=button border.fg!66,rounded corners,align=center,#1] {\usebeamerfont{button}\usebeamercolor[fg]{button}\insertgotosymbol #2};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample}
\begin{itemize}
\item \href{./myfile.pdf}{\mygotobutton[text width=3cm,minimum height=2cm]{Click here}}

\item \href{./myfile.pdf}{\beamergotobutton{Click here}}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]